# Theme in wp-content but my index.php search theme files in root

Tags: directory, wp-enqueue-style, paths

My file is in i.e in domain.com/wp-content/Themename/css/cssfile.css

But for example css files are looked in domain.com/css/cssfile

How to change this? The site isn't loading anything properly because of this!

Comment: what is the theme ?

Comment: https://github.com/technext/Imminent?files=1

This is the bootstrap theme. Site loaded on is http://fitclaw.com if you go to view source you are going to see where does it search for css js files ..

Comment: when I look the source of the site, I see the good URL for ressources from theme, like `wp-content/themes/Coming Soon/css/loader.css`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are adding your stylesheets like this in your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Which won't work. To construct the path dynamically, you need to use the PHP functions offered for this. Make sure your header has `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in it, and then enqueue your style in your theme's `functions.php` file as follows:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles' );

function enqueue_my_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'style-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
}
```

This will automatically prepend the theme's URI to your CSS file, and output it in your theme's header.